# Automatic column data type detection in Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark, databricks

In Databricks, using Pyspark I have a data frame with about 200 columns, which are all strings. I need to change the data type for each column to reflect its contents. Instead of creating a schema and manually enter all 200 columns and their respective data types, is there a way for Spark to auto detect them?